# Package name of the predetermined app of notes?

Tags: android

Hello I'm developing an app and I need the package name of the predetermined app android notes. The application that comes with android. The ''Notes'' App.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by predetermine app android notes?

Comment: @KapilVats The application that comes with android. The ''Notes'' App.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard Android "notes" app.

Comment: So...how I do to develop a simple "notes" app? @CommonsWare

Comment: i cant believe this comment (and sorry for this "too chatty" one, i had to say it)

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you have to try is an implicit intent, and hope that actually there is one or more apps in the device that can handle it.

Take a look at the [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), and [intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) reference.

Also, take a look at [openintents.org](http://openintents.org), a website that, as they say:

> ...collect, design, and implement open intents and interfaces to make
>   Android mobile applications work more closely together. We provide
>   samples and free applications to demonstrate their usage.